# Which event runs line by line in the DataGridView Windows Forms C #?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

how are you ?

I need an event that allows me to change the colors of the current line, according to color this informed in a field of the same row.

In asp.net I used the

```
gdvPB_RowDataBound (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
}
```

in C # but I did not find anything. Can anyone help me?

thanks !!

Comment: Pleae rephrase. You want to recolor a line on what condition? After some value is entered in a specific field? Also for reference (not only for OP but for those who'll be ansering as well), here's the complete list of the [DataGridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `DataBindingComplete` or `CellFormatting` witch could do what you want

edit : You could also use the Load event of the form to apply your formatting only once

Answer (score 0):

The current line is also the selected line, you may not need any event for that purpose, just use this:

```
youDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
```

If you want some kind of event looping through all the rows and apply some style on some row (instead of looping through the Rows collection), I think the `RowPostPaint`is OK, or even `RowsAdded` is great (apply style just one time at the beginning):

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowCount == 1)
        {
            switch (e.RowIndex)
            {
                //your case here
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
```

There are some other `Row-related events` which I think are also usable.